I'm unable to perform mobile performance testing like apk
There is no API to test. The app depends on incognito and firebase. I need to connect the mobile with jmeter.I tried it but unsuccessful.
How can I do it?
Kindly help. I have no idea about it. The instructors are asking thousands of dollars

I guess Firebase uses HTTP/2 protocol for communication with mobile devices so you will need HTTP2 Plugin for JMeter
The plugin can be installed using JMeter Plugins Manager
It can also act as a proxy and provide recording capabilities as well, see the comment in JMeter Github Issues for more details

The BlazeMeter http2 plugin has experimental support for enabling http2 recording in JMeter using the native JMeter proxy recorder.
It is a functionality that has not yet been officially released, but can be tested if desired in the latest alpha version.
If you download version 2.0.3-alpha.3
https://github.com/Blazemeter/jmeter-http2-plugin/releases
and add the following property in jmeter.properties or user.properties
HTTP2Sampler.proxy_enabled=true

When you are recording with the JMeter proxy, all requests will be captured through the plugin's http engine that supports http1.x and http2, as well as ALPN.

